# Adding large number of unique values in MySql that may cross the range of sql integer

Tags: mysql, sql, database, range, social-networking

I am building a simple social network and currently I am designing its database tables. I am  building a separate tables for comments. Each comment will have a unique comment id by which I will query them. The question is if we assume the situation that the site is becoming popular and a millions of users are posting tens of millions of comments, wouldn't at some point of time I will run out of range that the sql integer is providing? I don't have an idea how to do this or even if this situation is practical? If it is practical then how to handle this. I want my site to be scalable.

And how long should be the range of integer lets say for 'Users' table (for storing users having unique 'userid'), the 'Posts' table  (for storing posts having unique 'postid') and comments table. I am using MySql and I will be building my website using Servlets. Any other suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Chose the column type that appears to be suitable to you. If a `bigint` type really i not enough (it is...), then you will have to migrate one day. But that day will be long after your system is not used any more, believe me :-)

Comment: Completely agree with @arkascha . `BIGINT` should be ample for your needs for a very very long time.

Comment: thanks @arkascha and scgough for your suggestions, cleared my confusion.  thanks for helping :-)

Comment: But how do we decide about what range can we set for id fields of 'posts' and 'users' table.